# Ошибка при изменении цвета роли discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я решил сделать автоматическое изменение цвета роли. Написал следующий код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
  
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "g/")
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event 
async def on_ready(): 
 server = bot.get_server("807653017611534336") 
 return server 

async def runtime_background_task(): 
 colours = [0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF0] 
 i = 0 
 server = await on_ready() 
 role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="RGB-Tag") 
 while not bot.is_closed: 
  i = (i + 1) % 3 
  await bot.edit_role(server=server, role=role, colour=discord.Colour(colours[i])) 
  await asyncio.sleep(5)
bot.loop.create_task(runtime_background_task())

bot.run("SECRET-TOKEN")
```

В итоге выходит ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/colorol.py", line 13, in on_ready
    server = bot.get_server("807653017611534336")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_server'
```

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discord-py` не имеет метода `get_server`.

Для получения объекта сервера используйте `bot.get_guild(id)`

---

В `get_guild()` параметр `id` передается в виде числа `int`, а не строки `str`

Замените

```
server = await on_ready()
```

на

```
server = bot.get_guild(807653017611534336)
```

Comment: Эта проблема решилась. Но боявилась новая проблема: ```Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/colorol.py", line 14, in on_ready
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="RGB-Tag")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'```

Comment: Вы зачем-то пытаетесь вызвать асинхронную функцию `on_ready()`, да еще и получить от нее результат. Эта функция вызывается библиотекой `discord-py` только один раз - при запуске бота. Потом ее трогать больше не надо. Поэтому просто переместите строку получения сервера из `on_ready()` в вашу основную функцию и все. Дополнил ответ, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Заменил, но пишет ту же самую ошибку о том, что server не имеет атрибута roles.

Comment: Точно id в виде числа указали? Пишет именно server или NoneType не имеет атрибута?

Comment: Указал в виде числа. Теперь скрипт просто «зависает» на самом изменении роли. (```await role.edit(colour=0xFF0000)```)

Comment: Тут возможно дело уже в самом ограничении по времени на смену свойств роли. Бот не может менять роль каждые 5 миллисекунд. Попробуйте указать 5000 или сделать раз в 1 (60000 мс) минуту, может заработает?

Comment: Вса заработало. Спасибо за терпение и объяснение <3